# Error happening during template passing in springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am new to springboot and i came across this error on browser:

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Wed May 06 02:05:58 PDT 2020
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/institute/home.html]" - line 29, col 28)
```

The code of my InstituteController is:

```
package com.example.demo.controller;

import com.example.demo.dto.InstituteDto;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributes;

import javax.validation.Valid;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/institute")
public class InstituteController {

    @GetMapping("/home")
    private String instituteSave(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("institute", new InstituteDto());
        return "institute/home";
    }

    @PostMapping("/save")
    private String saveInstitute(@Valid @ModelAttribute("institute") InstituteDto instituteDto, BindingResult bindingResult, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
        if (!bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return null;
        } else {
            String error = bindingResult.getAllErrors().get(0).getDefaultMessage();
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("error",error);
            return "redirect:/institute/home";
        }
    }
}
```

The code of my InstituteDto is:

```
package com.example.demo.dto;

import com.example.demo.enums.Status;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.UniqueConstraint;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class InstituteDto {

    private Long id;
    @NotNull(message = "Institute name cannot be null")
    @NotBlank(message = "Institute name cannot be blank")
    private String name;
    @NotNull(message = "Institute address cannot be null")
    @NotBlank(message = "Institute address cannot be blank")
    private String address;
    @NotNull(message = "Institute officialWebsite cannot be null")
    @NotBlank(message = "Institute officialWebsite cannot be blank")
    private String officialWebsite;
    private Status status;
}
```

The code of my home.html is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Institute Home page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h3>Form</h3>
            <!--/*@thymesVar id="institute" type="institute"*/-->
            <form th:action="@{~/institute/save}" method="post" th:object="${institute}">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="institute_name">Institute name</label>
                    <input type="name" class="form-control" id="institute_name" aria-describedby="institute_name"
                           th:field="*{name}">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="address">Institute address</label>
                    <input type="name" class="form-control" id="address" aria-describedby="address" th:field="*{address}>
                    </div>

                    <div class=" form-group">
                    <label for="officialWebsite">Institute officialWebsite</label>
                    <input type="name" class="form-control" id="officialWebsite" aria-describedby="officialWebsite"
                           th:field="*{officialWebsite}>
                    </div>

                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class=" col-md-8">
                    <h3>List</h3>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I looked up some solution and some said to change the Controller annotation to RestController but this didn't solve my problem either.

What I am trying to do is bind the error message in the webpage and also get the inputs in model from the webpage.
What is causing this error and how do I rectify it?

Answer (score 1):

> You receive `template parsing` error because you missed tag to close in home.html

`<input>` tag in your file is not closed at line no 26.
Close that and try to run your code again.

```html
<input type="name" class="form-control" id="officialWebsite" aria-describedby="officialWebsite"
                           th:field="*{officialWebsite}/>
```

Why this happens? - because everything needs to be in valid XML in thymeleaf.
Check [History](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/fromhtmltohtmlviahtml.html)

and [Ref](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#what-kind-of-templates-can-thymeleaf-process)

Comment: this works,thank you but i have another html file with an unclosed input tag and same opertaions, and this works perfectly fine, why is that so?

Comment: thymeleaf process tags like xml - `all open tags should have a close tag`.

Comment: You can accept answer if it solved your problem.https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers